# React hook form - working with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, next.js, react-hook-form

On our support page, we had to display checkboxes for products to give the user the option to select the product(s) they have problems with.

I mapped through the checkboxes inside a component named CheckboxListItem:

[map inside an array of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZPH5.jpg)

The data (selected checkboxes) that we have to send to the server must have the exact shape in below pic, and the items were almost always sent in this structure.

[data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5JX0.jpg)

Everything seemed okay until our backend team reported something strange: sometimes they received data in a very odd and ambiguous way:

[posted data with odd structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud3HK.jpg)

I examined the code I wrote and noticed that when I click inside a checkbox to check or uncheck it, everything works well, but when I accidentally clicked between them, all the checked checkboxes became unchecked. When I logged the checkboxItems, I saw that odd structure. I tried to check one or two checkboxes again, and they worked as I expected. But when I looked at the log(the data that I was going to send to the server), I saw the exact odd structure again:

[the object with ids, are the checked items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/032js.jpg)

So, what was the problem?

I simply forgot to give the register function the specific name as the first argument when I was using it in side the ref prop :)

When the name is not mentioned in the register function, the checkbox will lose its value.

This could cause another strange problem:
**when you have mapped through an array of objects, but there is only one object-property and you have only one single checkbox to display.**

In this case, **React Hook Form cannot recognize the array-item as an object, so it converts it to a boolean typed value**:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nku1m.jpg)

So, when we do not mention the input name inside register, we could get different behavior in different situations, which is the opposite of what we want :)

We could fix this issue just by adding the name input inside register:

[add name value in to reg func](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ74x.jpg)

I also found another way to fix this issue:
we could also consider a separate name for each of the rendered checkboxes. **Using the `name + index` pattern could be a suitable solution in this case**:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xnEo.jpg)

so when you're working with react-hook-form, be careful with register function and the values which your're passing to it as a name or registerOptions.

Comment: Would you post your code instead of images?